# Checking for multiple lines with hasNextLine() method

Tags: java

I am having trouble with the `Scanner.hasNextLine()` method. Here is my code:

```
while(scan.hasNextLine()) {         
     definition = scan.nextLine();
     otherInfo = scan.nextLine();
     link = scan.nextLine();
}
```

As you can see, after the Scanner checks if there is another line, I take in three lines as input. The problem occurs at the end of my file. The Scanner scans the last line of the file and the while-loop is executed, even though there are not enough lines left to complete the loop without throwing a `NoSuchElementFound` exception.

Is there any way to use the `Scanner.hasNextLine()` method to check if there are multiple lines left in a file? Thank you for your time and any help you can provide.

Comment: For each line you want to read, you need to check if it exists

Comment: What *should* the code do with corrupted input, where there is not a multiple -of-3 lines of text, if it should not throw an exception saying "bad input"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if there is a next line for `otherInfo` and `link`, the check for `definition` is done in `while (scan.hasNextLine())`:

```
while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
    definition = scan.nextLine();

    if (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        otherInfo = scan.nextLine();

        if (scan.hasNextLine())
            link = scan.nextLine();
    }
}
```

but the problem is what do you make out of this loop?  
Just reading the lines without saving them, or printing them?  
The loop finishes at some point and the 3 variables have their last 3 values.

Comment: Thank you for your response! This worked. I store the values definition, link, and otherInfo into an Object called an Entry, and then store Entry objects into an arrayList. Then I print out all the Entry objects in the list.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to put your variables in a data structure such as an `ArrayList` and then do something like:

```
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
while(scan.hasNextLine()) {         
    arr.add(scan.nextLine());
}
```

This way you ensure that there is a next line and you don't have to hardcode assigning the variables.

Then `arr[0]` would be `definition`, `arr[1]` would be `otherInfo` and `arr[2]` would be `link`

Comment: Won't this just throw an index out of bounds exception when it scans the 4th line? His input file must have at least 4 lines to produce the error he's seeing (possibly ending in a blank line or something).

Comment: @mkasberg True. I changed it to an `ArrayList`. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

Does your file always have exactly 3 things you care about? If so, simplify the problem by using a for loop rather than a while loop. This way you don't need to worry about a trailing newline (which is common) messing you up.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {         
    definition = scan.nextLine();
    otherInfo = scan.nextLine();
    link = scan.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Yep the trailing new line is my problem; there are not always three things I care about. Some of the entries do not have "otherInfo" lines.